# SQLAlchemy core does not detect ForiegnKey in sqlite DB

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables 'Generations' and 'Results' created using SQL Alchemy with a foreign key relation Generations.individual == Results.hash

However when I load the DB I can't get SQLAlchemy to detect the FK relation. I can query the FK in the table object, so why the NoForeignKeysError?

Connecting;

```
class ForeignKeysListener(sa.interfaces.PoolListener):
    def connect(self, dbapi_con, con_record):
        db_cursor = dbapi_con.execute('pragma foreign_keys=ON')

path_db = r"sqlite:///C:\ExportDir\DB\test.sql"
engine = sa.create_engine(path_db, echo=0, listeners=[util_sa.ForeignKeysListener()])
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

metadata = sa.MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine)
```

The two tables have the following columns;

```
generations_table = metadata.tables['Generations']
print(generations_table.columns) 
# ['Generations.id', 'Generations.gen', 'Generations.individual']

results_table = metadata.tables['Results']
print(results_table.columns)
# ['Results.hash', 'Results.start', 'Results.finish', 'Results.var_c_var0', 'Results.var_c_var1', 'Results.obj_c_obj1', 'Results.obj_c_obj2']
```

And I can see the following fk properties;

```
print("gens_table.foreign_keys",generations_table.foreign_keys)
# gens_table.foreign_keys set([ForeignKey(u'Results.hash')])
fk = generations_table.foreign_keys.pop()
print("fk.column",fk.column)
# fk.column Results.hash
print("fk.parent",fk.parent)
# fk.parent Generations.individual
```

However the following raises an error

```
j = sa.join(generations_table, results_table)
stmt = sa.select([generations_table]).select_from(j)
```

NoForeignKeysError: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'Generations' and 'Results'.

Whereas the manually defining the join columns works;

```
j = sa.join(generations_table, results_table, generations_table.c.individual == results_table.c.hash)
stmt = sa.select([generations_table]).select_from(j)
```

Any ideas on how to further debug this?

Answer (score 0):

After some more effort I think the problem is that the MetaData was not bound to the engine.

So my solution is;

```
engine = sa.create_engine(path_db, echo=0, listeners=[util_sa.ForeignKeysListener()])
metadata = sa.MetaData(bind=engine)
metadata.reflect()
```

And the join now works.